# Dynamic Object C# 4.0 , Creating columns at runtime from Pre-defined values

Tags: c#-4.0

I have used dynamic object but here is a situation where the column names comes from a pre-defined string arrays.How can i create objects at runtime with these pre-defined set of column values?.
 The reason why i wanted to do this way is to create a custom class and add custom validation attributes in it so that i can use reflection at runtime to populate values to these dynamic objects mapped to my custom class and validate the values using a single function.

```
 dynamic x = new MyCustomClass();
 x.Name = "Jones"; // The Field or Column name "Name" comes from a array of strings.

 Validator.Validate(x); //Here i use reflection to iterate through the custom attributes on MyCustomClass and validate them based on conditions.
```

Is it possible to do something like this  `x."Name" = "Jones"`;  :-)

Comment: expando objects look like they'll do what you're after - check 3/4 down in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest perhaps adding an indexer property to your MyCustomClass?

```
public string this[string binder] {
    get { 
        string result;
        return (this.TryGetMember(binder, out result)) ? result : string.Empty
    }
    set {
        this.TrySetMember(binder, value);
    }
}

x["Name"] = "Jones";
```